# How to write exporter plugin for own Game Engine

Tags: python, scripting

I'd like to write exporting plug-in for Blender on Linux. The main feature I'm going to have exporting to JSON or XML (easy to check and edit) with valid for my engine textures and PBR materials (next step is convert JSON or XML to binary format). I'd like to being this plug-in shown somewhere in Blender menus or in `File > Export > Export to ... engine format.` menu.

Comment: Have a look at the operator file export script template in the templates > python menu of the text editor.